# What kind of maze was Dom looking for in Inception?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

In *Inception*, Dom gives Ariadne two minutes to make a maze that takes one minute to solve. Why was the maze with concentric circles "more like it". What was Dom looking for exactly? Why were the other ones inferior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What he was looking for was stated fairly precisely.  I've added a few words here:

> You have (*a maximum of*) two minutes to draw a maze that takes me (*a minimum of*) one minute to solve

The first two mazes are too easy, with a path that goes from one end of the maze to the other.  He solves them very quickly.  The concentric circle maze was much harder, requires more searching through the entire space to find the path through to the next layer.  She even uses the notebook cover to create it, so she is not mentally constrained by the grid lines.

[image]

He doesn't care what the maze looks like, merely that she is creative enough to create a puzzle too hard to solve quickly.

He needed someone that could create a dream environment complex enough that the projections find it too hard to easily navigate to find (and kill) the architect.

I do appreciate the fact that the circular maze looks unsolvable.  I can't explain that other than this is a small mistake in the movie.  I personally don't think there is more to this than the first two mazes were too easy.

Comment: What made the first maze "too easy"? The layout of the first maze and the circles were similar. They both forced the solver to go through a specific path. I'm beginning to think that although the mazes were similar, the circles require less 'building' material?

Comment: You see him solve the first maze in seconds - and him pause and struggle with the second.  less "building" material doesn't really make much sense in terms of dreams.  We see Ariadne manipulate a huge chunk of Paris scenery for fun on only her second time in the dream.

Comment: Yes and I'm pretty sure he can drag his pen through the concentric circles in seconds as well. I guess a helpful subquestion would be, why did he stop and pause with the circle maze? Also I don't see how manipulating huge chunks of scenery has anything to do with building material. Arthur gives the example of the penrose steps to hide the boundaries of the level, seemingly suggesting constructing every detail isn't necessary and it would be better to be efficient with the construction as the dreamer will fill in the details. Her manipulation of a dream and its construction are separate.

Comment: Well, I'm just going to have to disagree with you on this point - I think the concentric circle maze appears much more complex than the linear one she tries first.  I personally think he's merely looking for a maze that will slow him down for a minute.

Comment: Any maze that takes 2 minutes to build with a pen and small piece of paper should theoretically be able to be solved within a short span of time. I think the essence of his test was create a maze that is \textit{simple} to construct but relatively not so easy to solve. Also, from a glimpse in the movie, it seemed as if a circular uninterrupted loop finished the maze, but upon a closer look, if one were to enter the maze, they would have no idea whether going left or right is correct, which is distinct from the others as there is a clear indication of what the correct path is.

Comment: Yes I agree with you now that I see a closer look at the maze. But I also don't understand why you rephrase the question. Clearly one was harder to solve than the other, but why was it? Thanks for editing your response.

Comment: It wasn't hugely important for me to add the (minimum/maximum of) - but those are the implied terms of the specification.  He didn't care if she took less than two minutes as long as it takes him at least one minute to solve.

Comment: Again, the terms of the specification is not very relevant (obviously) and neither are the times. As I said, the maze above doesn't exactly require a minute to complete. The point is that from Dom's perspective, it is easy to complete as he knows the layout. But from say a 2D person living in the paper, it wouldn't be so easy to solve. The first two are different in this way. This distinction is important to escape the projections in the dream. Mazes that are hard to solve irl are definitely hard to solve in paper, which serves the purpose of the test.

Comment: Another thing that's interesting to note is that adding splits in a maze is much easier in concentric circles. Also, you have no sense of direction when in a circular maze.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that circular maze in unsolvable? Working from the center backwards get me into a dead-end. What am I missing?

Comment: @firtydank you can't start at the center; the idea is to enter at one side and exit at another.

Comment: @Luciano - Thanks for clarifying, but I only see one exit. If the entrance is behind his hand, that makes for a really simple maze. Anyway this is probably offtopic.

Comment: Two downvotes and yet no alternative answer.  I do appreciate that the maze does look problematic but I can't explain that other than sloppiness from the director.  I watched Inception last night partially to see this scene again, and he does run through the first two very quickly then pauses on the circular one and says "that's more like it"

Answer (score 4):

Ariadne's winning maze is circular - structurally similar to the Penrose staircase as well as the drawing Cobb presents of consciousness (the mind that creates and perceives its existence simultaneously). The pinwheel and spinning top are also circular.

The "good" mazes in Inception are all depicted this way because circularity is associated with paradox and Inception argues that while subconscious communication is not possible on the rational level (which can always trace the "genesis of the idea") it can be accomplished subliminally if the rational mind is distracted with paradoxical forms while the real message is handed to the viewer/listener using simple, positive, creative and symbolic forms. Thus also Eames (the forger) replacing Nash (the mathematician), etc. etc.

http://filmreadings.com/2015/12/31/a-skeleton-key-to-inception/

This review might be interesting if you want to dig deeper in these ideas - the interpretation is of Inception as a maze for the audience whose circular and paradoxical structure is a deliberate if playful attempt to confuse and distract the audience while the director pulls off his own meta-heist.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the image posted by @iandotkelly there is one more thing that makes the desired maze stand out.

It is a maze within a maze within a maze. It is constructed of several layers of mazing, very similar to the dreams that the team has to navigate through later on.

So by designing the last maze, Ariadne has used the same concept that they are planning to use later on in their dreams.

And if the maze is really unsolvable - at least for Dom - that might be a further hint of him not being able to escape the last layer of the maze he is actually in throughout the entire movie.